# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString missing some characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, httputility

I'm trying to extract en email with the `+` special character but for some reason the `ParseQueryString` skips it:

```
namespace ParsingProblem
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {        
                var uri = new System.Uri("callback://gmailauth/#email=mypersonalemail15+1@gmail.com");
                var parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Fragment);
                var email = parsed["#email"];
                // Email is: mypersonalemail15 1@gmail.com and it should be mypersonalemail15+1@gmail.com
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That is working as expected. If you want to get the raw value (because your caller gave you an invalid value like this one) then manually parse it from `uri.Fragment` .

Answer (score 1):

The `+` symbol in a URL is interpreted as a space character. To fix that, you need to URL encode the email address first. For example:

```
var urlEncodedEmail = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("mypersonalemail15+1@gmail.com");
var uri = new System.Uri($"callback://gmailauth/#email={urlEncodedEmail}");
var parsed = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Fragment);
var email = parsed["#email"];
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot do that as I only receive the whole uri as you I show before. And in order to access the email I have to parse the uri which would put me in the same problem

Comment: Then whatever is sending you that URL needs fixing as it is broken.

Comment: Another example, an email address can contain `&`, so if the email passed to you was `me&you@gmail.com`, then the parsing would give you `me` which is even more broken.

Comment: And if you are absolutely unable to fix the root of the problem, you are going to have to manually parse the email address out of there by yourself.